# how to export layer with alpha channel from GIMP to Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, export, transparency

I am trying to export a layer from GIMP to Photoshop. The layer is added with alpha channel and when i try to export to Photoshop it converts into white color.

[image: image in photoshop]

[image: image in gimp]

Answer (score 1):

Export using some format that preserves transparency (PNG...)